# Get available controls from a Form

Tags: c#, winforms

How do I get available controls from a [Windows Forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms) form using C#?

Comment: what do you mean with "Available"?

Comment: I wish you guys would spend a minute thinking about how to phrase your question rather than just hitting submit with the first thing that comes to your mind. We're not telepathic here, you know.

Comment: @Cerebrus: I agree that the quality of the question is really awful, but there are many people whose English skills are so poor that writing a question like this could've taken half an hour with a dictionary in hand. Sad, I know.

Comment: @Ravi: Perhaps you want to get the available design-time controls in the Visual Studio Toolbox?

Answer (score 22):

Or, ProfK's solution in enumerable syntax:

```
public static IEnumerable<Control> GetControls(Control form) {
    foreach (Control childControl in form.Controls) {   // Recurse child controls.
        foreach (Control grandChild in GetControls(childControl)) {
            yield return grandChild;
        }
        yield return childControl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Anything that will include menuitems as well (not Controls) but still ?

Answer (score 6):

Try this method in your form.  It will recursively get all controls on your form, and their children:

```
public static List<Control> GetControls(Control form)
{
    var controlList = new List<Control>();

    foreach (Control childControl in form.Controls)
    {
        // Recurse child controls.
        controlList.AddRange(GetControls(childControl));
        controlList.Add(childControl);
    }
    return controlList;
}
```

Then call it with a:

```
List<Control> availControls = GetControls(this);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean all controls on the form.
So simply you can use `Controls` property inside your form object.

```
foreach(Control c in this.Controls)
{
   //TODO:
}
```

Comment: That would have to be recursive for any child controls that are containers of other controls.