# How to get a collection of the field objects of the form?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, reflection, localization

I have a form with a number of context menus (of the ContextMenuStrip type). They are private fields of the form. How can I get a collection of those objects to perform some action on them (localizing).

Comment: How do you intend to use the fields for localization?

Comment: field.Text = field.Text.Translate(), where Translate - extension method which use resx file for finding the transation of the string.

Comment: Actually, i have a recursive method PerformActionOnContextMenu(ContextMenuStrip menu, Action<ContextMenuStrip > action) takes translation action.

Comment: Localization is a built-in feature of Winforms.  Trying to cook your own is almost always a mistake, tough to maintain and expensive to send out and get localized by a service.  Use the form's Localizable and Language properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use erikkallen's Enumerator on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/653284/get-available-controls-from-form-using-c) to get ALL controls.

Then use

```
foreach(var contr in GetControls(this))
    if (contr is ContextMenuStrip)
    {
        var cms = (contr as ContextMenuStrip);
        cms.Text.Translate();
    }
```