# C# Loop window form elements

Tags: c#, windows, forms, combobox

I have a window form that has a couple of combo boxes.
What I need accomplished is to have every combo box that has items to have their selected index set to 0. Rather than do every combo box by name manually, is there a function that returns all the children by type. Or to get all the children and compare their type to that of the combobox element?

@noah, your original code did not work at first, but all I needed was the reminder that the children are called controls (thanks).

With that I made a recursive function that sets all combo boxes not just the direct descendants of the main form:

```
private void recursiveSetComboBox(Control element)
{
    foreach (Control a in element.Controls)
    {
        if (a.Controls.Count != 0)
            recursiveSetComboBox(a);
        else if (a.GetType().Name == "ComboBox")
        {
            ComboBox b = (ComboBox)a;

            b.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }
    }
}

recursiveSetComboBox(this);
```

Comment: You can just write `a is ComboBox` to check the type...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how I would do it:

```
foreach (var comboBox in myForm.Controls.OfType<ComboBox>())
{
    comboBox.SelectedIndex = 0;
}
```

If the combo boxes are not directly on the form but inside a container (group box, panel, etc.) then use that instead of myForm.

Comment: @Serge-appTranslator: yes, it certainly is.

Comment: What happens if the combobox is inside of a pannel or a groupbox?

Comment: See my answer that includes recursion :)

Comment: @LeopoldScotch: recursion is only needed when they are in different containers or on different levels. If they are all directly contained in the same container, recursion is not necessary, obviously.

Comment: @noah1989 True, but if you want to be double sure that you find all the controls you may as well include the recursion.

Comment: @LeopoldScotch I'd rather keep it simple and not include recursion unless necessary.

Comment: Yes, but he asked for it to find 'every' control on a form. Your code only finds every combobox in the parent control. No big deal anyway, he used recursion in the end :)

Answer (score 2):

You will have to use a recursive function to check each control and it's children.. try this:

```
public void CheckForComboBox(Control crl)
{
foreach (Control crl in this) {

    if (crl is ComboBox && ((ComboBox)crl).Items.Count > 0) {
        ((ComboBox)crl).SelectedIndex = 1;
    } else if (crl.Controls != null && crl.Controls.Count > 0) {
        CheckForComboBox(crl);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can enumerate the controls and filter them using Linq:

```
foreach (var comboBox in yourForm.Controls.OfType<ComboBox>())
{
}
```

But if you have controls inside of another control (like comboboxes inside a panel), then you'll have to make a recursive version.

Answer (score 1):

When the controls are included in a group box, you can do this

```
 foreach (Control group in this.Controls)             //Control combo in this.Controls)
            {

                if (group.GetType().Name == "GroupBox")  //(con is ComboBox)
                {
                    foreach (Control con in group.Controls)
                    {
                        if (con.GetType().Name == "ComboBox")
                        {

                            ComboBox combo = (ComboBox)con;
                            _dtStaff=new DataTable();
                              _dtStaff = _staff.getStaffList();
                            combo.DataSource = _dtStaff;
                            combo.DisplayMember = _dtStaff.Columns[1].ToString();
                            combo.ValueMember = _dtStaff.Columns[0].ToString();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the controls in a form in this way:

```
foreach(Control c in MyForm.Controls)
{
//Do something here
}
```

But remember that one of this controls could be a groupox or a panel that has controls inside, so you will need some kind of recursive function that return all the controls in a form no matter if one control is inside other, and then filter the collection by the type.

But we have good luck, other post in Stackoverflow has the solution to this problem: [Get available controls from a form using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/653284/get-available-controls-from-form-using-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the controls on your form like this:

```
foreach (Control control in MyForm.Controls) {
     // test control type
}
```

Note that if you embed a control (e.g. put it in a table layout panel) then this will not find your control.

Instead, you need to recursively call the method to find your controls and each time check whether the control you are looking at [has child controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.haschildren%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)