# Get control by name, including children

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, controls

I'm trying to get a control by name. I wrote the following code:

```
public Control GetControlByName(string name)
{
    Control currentControl; 

    for(int i = 0,count = Controls.Count; i < count; i++)
    {
        currentControl = Controls[i];

        if (currentControl.HasChildren)
        {
            while (currentControl.HasChildren)
            {
                for(int x = 0,size = currentControl.Controls.Count; x < size; x++)
                {
                    currentControl = currentControl.Controls[x];

                    if (currentControl.Name.Equals(name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                    {
                        return currentControl;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (currentControl.Name.Equals(name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                return currentControl;
            }
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

It only ever returns null. Can someone point out my mistake? Any help or ways to improve this code are welcomed.

Comment: currentControl = currentControl.Controls[x]; in teh loop looks suspect

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/653284/get-available-controls-from-form-using-c-sharp

Comment: Why aren't you using recursion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually wrote some extension methods at work to do just this thing:

```
public static class MyExensions ()
{
    public static Control FindControlRecursively (this Control control, string name)
    {
        Control result = null;

        if (control.ID.Equals (name))
        {
            result = control;
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (var child in control.Children)
            {
                result = child.FindControlRecursively (name);

                if (result != null)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    public static T FindControlRecursively<T> (this Control control, string name)
        where T: Control
    {
        return control.FindControlRecursively (name) as T;
    }
}
```

Note: *Null checks removed for the sake of simplicity.*

You can use it to find, say, a `TextBox` on your form like so:

```
public class MyForm : Form
{
    public void SetSomeText ()
    {
        var control = this.FindControlRecursively<TextBox> ("myTextboxName");

        if (control != null)
        {
            control.Text = "I found it!";
        }

        // Or...

        var control2 = this.FindControlRecursively ("myTextboxName2") as TextBox;

        if (control != null)
        {
            control2.Text = "I found this one, also!";
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit**

Of course, this is a *depth-first* algorithm, which might be slow depending on how deep your control chain is.  You might rewrite it to use a *breadth-first* algorithm if you see that it is too slow.

Answer (score 13):

Just use the Controls collection [Find](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) method:

```
            var aoControls = this.Controls.Find("MyControlName", true);
            if ((aoControls != null) && (aoControls.Length != 0))
            {
                Control foundControl = aoControls[0];
            }
```

Comment: Is this recursive?  Will it find children of children?

Comment: @User: Yes, the second parameter to Find makes it so.

Answer (score 1):

A slight tweak for if you're **not** using `System.Windows.Forms` (this is what `.Find(string, bool)` works off too)

```
public static class MyExensions
{
    public static Control FindControlRecursively(this Control control, string name)
    {
        Control result = null;

        if (control.ID.Equals(name))
        {
            result = control;
        }
        else
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < control.Controls.Count; i++)
            {
                result = control.Controls[i].FindControlRecursively(name);

                if (result != null)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    public static T FindControlRecursively<T>(this Control control, string name)
        where T : Control
    {
        return control.FindControlRecursively(name) as T;
    }
}
```

p.s. Yes I know it's an old question, but in case it helps