# Accessing other buttons from one button's "click" method

Tags: c#

How can I access other buttons from click method of one button? I'm working in Milestone SDK (c#, visual studio).

I've tried to use "this.", but it obviously doesn't work... (I'm novice in c#)...

In example below I can change "CONTENT" for bbt button object (bbt.Content = "TEST";):

```
private void bbt_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
var bbt = sender as Button;

bbt.Content = "TEST";
}
```

but how can I change content for other buttons, defined in my code? For example, another button name is "action1"?

Maybe there is a way to declare something like that:

```
var bbt = sender as Button;
```

but for all other buttons so I can access them like I'm accessing "bbt"?

Would like to have a code that will allow mi to do:

```
action1.Content = "TEST";
```

where action1 is another button.

It looks like I need to add some prefix before referring to "action1", because otherwise it's not visible and generates:

> CS0103 The name 'action1' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Yes, you can create a single event handler for multiple controls and cast `object sender` to the appropriate type of the control. As for your problem accessing `action1`, there isn't enough information present to know. For starters, is this WinForms? WPF? Something else?

Comment: The classic example of this is writing a calculator with a numeric keypad. In this case all the buttons will have one of the digits 0..9 as their Text property. In this case, you can use the same handler for all the numeric buttons, with code like `if (sender is Button btn) { /* code to extract digit from Text property and do the calculator work */ }`

Comment: Is action1 and bbt in the same form?

Comment: Yes, they are on the same form.

Basically I use Milestone SDK (camera VMS). Did mockup in regular c# and it worked fine, the problem is that I need to stick with Milestone SDK ActiveOverlay

Comment: Here is the link to whole code - maybe you guys can help me with that: 

https://shrib.com/#IcinRLal40GYR48ZEpCf

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to change the button label.
If the button already exist just use:

`private void bbt_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   bbt.Text= "TEST";
}`

Comment: Yes, but the problem is that I need to change the label of the other button, called "action1", defined in the same way like bbt. So the perfect solution would be: action1.Content="test"; but this generates: CS0103 The name 'action1' does not exist in the current context

Answer (score 0):

If you have a container like a `flowLayoutPanel,panels` where the child is buttons you can use the `forloop` to get all the `buttons` and change it `contents`

```
//if without a container you must Name your buttons to button1,button2,button3
int i=0;
while(true){
  i++;
 Button button = new Button();
 button.Name = "button"+i.toString();//output button1 to n
 WindowsFormName.Controls.Add(button);
}


private void bbt_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

  //loop all controls
  int y=0;
  foreach(Control control in WindowsFormName.Controls){

  y++;

  string name = "Button"+y.toString();

    //check if names are button1 or buttonN
  if(control.Name.Equals(name){
        control.Content = "TEST";
    }
   }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, but is there a way I can do it without flowlayoutpanel?

Comment: Please check the whole code - I define buttons in different way: 
https://shrib.com/#IcinRLal40GYR48ZEpCf

Answer (score 0):

If the button was at the same hierarchy as the button being clicked you should be able to access it normally (e.g. action1.Text = "hello world";). I believe your problem may be that the button is on a child control.

If that is the case you have to write some type of recursive code to find the desired button (see the answer to this post to search for a control recursively [Get control by name, including children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8737091/get-control-by-name-including-children))

Then call it:

```
var actionButton = this.FindControlRecursively<Button> ("action1");
```

Comment: I think that this is what I need in general, but unfortunatelly it generates an error: 
CS1061
'ActiveElementsOverlayBackgroundPlugin' does not contain a definition for 'FindControlRecursively' and no accessible extension method 'FindControlRecursively' accepting a first argument of type 'ActiveElementsOverlayBackgroundPlugin' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Your problem seems to be the ActiveOverlay, since I've never used it I don't know how to overcome this issue.